# I cannot reference a static C++/clr library in other .Net project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have an unmanaged code that is statically compiled,

I created a C++/CLR wrapper and reference the unmanaged code through "Add Reference" Option

I get this error when i build it

```
mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease'
```

then i changed the configuration option of my C++/CLR wrapper from dll(dynamic library to static library). everything compiled well

But when i try referencing it with a console app, that will consume the api through "Add Reference" > "Project"

i get this error "cannot add reference" what am i getting wrong in this setup?

meanwhile when c++/clr wrapper is in dynamic library option, my console app references it... successfully

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is what worked for me [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8b3e7a9d-1c7b-4813-99a1-7cdf040aa768/i-cannot-reference-a-static-cclr-library-in-other-net-project?forum=vclanguage&prof=required)... it has something to the RuntimeLibrary Type... CLR projects are dynamic and MD compatible..... so when you are trying to create a non-clr project make sure its compatible with CLR project